# Compiler error for network call syntax Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I can't figured it out what is wrong with the code. Please help. The app can archive with Xcode without any errors but not with third party platform. Thank you.

The error when compiling with third party platform

> ❌ /Users/App/APICall.swift:636:132: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'  APIManager.request.loadUser(name: name,
> code: code) { (userId, success) in success("(userId)") } failure: {
> (error, errorStr) in failure(error,errorStr) }  ^
>
> ❌ /Users/App/APICall.swift:636:140: consecutive statements on a line
> must be separated by ';' 
> APIManager.request.loadUser(name: name,
> code: code) { (userId, success) in success("(userId)") } failure: {
> (error, errorStr) in failure(error,errorStr) }  ^
>
> ❌ /Users/App/APICall.swift:636:140: expected expression
> APIManager.request.loadUser(name: name, code: code) { (userId,
> success) in success("(userId)") } failure: { (error, errorStr) in
> failure(error,errorStr) }  ^
>
> ❌ /Users/App/APICall.swift:636:77: missing argument for parameter
> 'success' in call
> APIManager.request.loadUser(name: name, code: code)
> { (userId, success) in success("(userId)") } failure: { (error,
> errorStr) in failure(error,errorStr) }  ^
>
> ❌ /Users/App/APICall.swift:636:133: expression resolves to an unused
> function
> APIManager.request.loadUser(name: name, code: code) {
> (userId, success) in success("(userId)") } failure: { (error,
> errorStr) in failure(error,errorStr) }  ^
>
> ❌ /Users/App/APICall.swift:636:142: closure expression is unused
> APIManager.request.loadUser(name: name, code: code) { (userId,
> success) in success("(userId)") } failure: { (error, errorStr) in
> failure(error,errorStr) }  ^~~~~~~

```
func updateUser(name: String, code: String, success: @escaping ((_ userCode: String) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((_ error: APIManager.UpdateError, _ errorMessage: String) -> Void)) {
        APIManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success(let data):
                            let json : [String: JSON] = JSON(data).dictionaryValue
                            
                            if (json["status"] == "success") {
                               APIManager.request.loadUser(name: name, code: code) { (userId, success) in
                                    success("\(userId)")
                                } failure: { (error, errorStr) in
                                    failure(error,errorStr) }
                            } else  {
                                failure(APIManager.UpdateError(rawValue: json["error"]!.intValue)!, json["error_message"]!.stringValue)
                            }
                        case .failure(_):
                               print("Call failed.")
                            }
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Comment: It's missing a comma: `} failure: {` => `}, failure: {`. Just comment that call at least. If you comment the whole code of `APIManager.request.loadUser(name: name`, does your code compile? If yes, start rewriting it and let autocompletion help you.

Comment: hi, when I add the comma Xcode is giving me error "cannot find 'error' in scope'.

Comment: I'd comment ALL that method call (at least what's inside `func updateUser(...){  /*...*/ }`, then I'd rewrite piece by piece each call with autocomplete helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a Swift 5.3 language feature. See

https://www.biteinteractive.com/swift-5-3-and-trailing-closures/

The problem is that you are not using Swift 5.3. You need to update your Xcode (or the “third party platform” needs to update its Swift compiler).

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I ran `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc --version` and the `Swift version is 5.3.2`. The Xcode I'm using is 12.4. Does it mean it is the third party platform needs to update their compiler?

Comment: You are sort of concealing the key info, namely what this "third party platform" is. But yeah, if they are not using Swift 5.3, you get this error.

Comment: Thanks! It took me awhile to find where to set the version. It was set to Xcode 11.2 before. Now it is good!! Thanks!!